# Access Report Year should be change after April every Year

Tags: vba, ms-access

The session is starting from every year from April to March.

The report needs to publish in twice in that year first report in October and another in March.

In both conditions year will be `2019-20`.

After March session will change then the year will also automatically changed `2020-21`.

How to resolve it?

Below expression will not work on this condition:

`Format(Date(),"yyyy-") & Right(Year(Date())+1,2)`

Comment: I don't understand. Please add some sample data and result, of what you expect when.

Comment: You want to calculate the session year for each record?

Comment: @Rev, I have students marksheet on the the top of marksheet it should appear in this year(2019) Half Yearly examination 2019-20 and on the next year in the month of March Final Examination will conduct on that time it should appear Final Examination 2019-20. Instead of Final Examination 2020-21. Yes, once session will change on the month april it should Half yearly examination 2020-21 and same things will go on Final Exam. Overall I school session start from month April to March means this year it should be 2019-20 for coming year 2020-21, 2021-22 so on.

Comment: @June, it should appear on the top of every students marksheet. Afterwards their name, mother's name, father's name and so on details will come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That needs an adjustment to the fiscal year, which can be done like this:

```
=Format(Year(DateAdd("m",-3,Date()))*100+(Year(DateAdd("m",-3,Date()))+1) Mod 100,"0000-00")
```

This offsets the date of the fiscal year to match a pseudo calendar year, thus allowing you to extract year and month as for any calendar year. The first year is returned in full and multiplied with 100: 201900 and added to the decade part of the second year: 201900 + 20 = 201920. This is finally formatted to have a dash: 2019-20.

Comment: can you explain that expression you posted. What it does and how?

Comment: Yes. It offsets the date of the fiscal year to match a pseudo calendar year, thus allowing you to extract year and month as for any calendar year. The first year is returned in full and multiplied with 100: `201900` and added to the decade part of the second year: `201900 + 20 = 201920`. This is finally formatted to have a dash: `2019-20`.

Comment: year will auto change when April months start or not?

Comment: That you will have to check out.

Comment: @ Gustav, I checked not working. its showing 2020-21 in current date. On April 2020 its showing  2020-21.

Comment: OK. Your offset is backward, not forward. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

So reports between April 2019 and Mar 2020 should show 2019-20.

Use conditional IIf:

`IIf(Month(Date()) < 3, Year(Date()) - 1 & "-" & Format(Date(),"YY"), Year(Date()) & "-" & Right(Year(Date()) + 1, 2))`

Problem with using Date() to calculate this is if report for March is run on April 1, calculation will be wrong. Might be best to reference textbox on form for beginning year.

Comment: Till 31 March it will not changed